# swiftで値のべき乗を返すプログラムのエラー

Tags: swift

swift2.0で値の累乗を返すプログラムのエラーが出てしまいます。原因はなんでしょうか？
ご教授お願いします。

//追記いたしました//

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class pcscoredistance{

    //数の累乗を求めるプログラム
    func ruizyou(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double {

        let ruizyou1 = pow(lhs, rhs)
        return ruizyou1
    }
    var n = ruizyou(-9.0, rhs: 2.0)//Extra argument 'rhs' in call というエラー
}
```

Comment: Xcode 7、Swift 2.0では、その関数呼び出しの書式でエラーになりません。そちらの編集＋実行環境をお知らせください。

Comment: Xcode 7、Swift 2.0を使用しております。

Comment: class部分を見せてくださいませんか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。追記いたします。

Answer (score 1):

Swift 2.0では

```
var n = ruizyou(4.0, rhs:2.0)
```

で、シンタックスエラーになりません。（Xcode.7.1.1のPlaygroundで確認）

Swift 1.2では

```
var n = ruizyou(4.0, 2.0)
```

と、第2引数のラベルを外すと、シンタックスエラーになりません。（Xcode 6.4のPlaygroundで確認）

---

*質問文が更新されたことによる、追記：*

関数（メソッド）の書式（Syntax）の問題でなく、インスタンス変数（プロパティ）の宣言のしかたの問題です。インスタンス変数の宣言時に、静的でない（`0.0`とか`1.0`など、決まった値にきまらない）値を初期値とすることはできません。

```
var n = ruizyou(-9.0, rhs: 2.0)
```

を

```
var n = 0.0
```

などとすると、エラーは出なくなるでしょう。
メソッドを使った、動的な値を初期値とするには、クラスのイニシアライザで、それを行います。

```
// Swift 2.0
import UIKit
// import Foundation // UIKitをインポートしたら、Foundationのインポートは不用。

class PcScoreDistance{ // クラス名は大文字で始める。インスタンス名を小文字で始めることで、混乱を防げる。
    //数の累乗を求めるプログラム
    func ruizyou(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double {
        // let ruizyou1 = pow(lhs, rhs)
        // return ruizyou1
        return pow(lhs, rhs)
    }
    var n: Double = 0.0 // とりあえず、0.0で初期化。

    // イニシアライザ
    init() {
        n = self.ruizyou(-9.0, rhs: 2.0) // メソッドのレシーバselfが必要。
    }
}

let object = PcScoreDistance()
object.n // 出力：81
```

もうひとつ修正案を出しておきます。これはメソッド`ruizyou()`を、クラスの外に出して、独立した関数として定義します。

```
// Swift 2.0
import UIKit

//数の累乗を求めるプログラム
func Ruizyou(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double { // 独立した関数は、大文字で始めたほうが、Objective-Cからある過去の資産と、相性がいい。
    return pow(lhs, rhs)
}

class PcScoreDistance{
    var n: Double = Ruizyou(-9.0, rhs: 2.0)
}

let object = PcScoreDistance()
object.n // 出力：81
```

Comment: その構文で、//Extra argument 'rhs' in callというエラーが出てします。

Comment: @naoei 回答を更新しました。

Answer (score -2):

呼び出し時、ラベルが必要な気がします

```
var n = ruizyou(4.0, rhs:2.0)
```

Comment: そのように記述すると、Extra argument 'rhs' in callというエラーが出てしまいます。

Answer (score -2):

`func`の前に`class`修飾子をつけてみて

```
class func ruizyou(lhs: Double, rhs: Double) -> Double {
   ...
}
```

だとどうでしょう？

（もしかしたら`var n`の方にも`class`が必要になってくるかもしれません。）